# R console and `didBecomeActive` messages

Tags: r, emacs, osx-mavericks, ess, rgui

**TL;DR**: In RGUI and ESS, what are the `didBecomeActive` messages and how do I suppress them?

---

Working with the OSX RGUI 3.0.3 in OSX 10.9.2, the console displays what look like logging messages 
Whenever the RGUI app becomes active. See the screenshot below

[image: RGUI]

Something similar happens in when I interact with R from within emacs, using ESS. Usually this happens whenever I use the default graphic device, for example invoking a simple `plot` function. When I close the window containing the graph or simply refocus to emacs another `didBecomeActive` message. With ESS this is particularly annoying because the buffer has become read-only and I cannot directly interact with the console (a workaround is to `C-c C-q` to try and quit the R process but then cancel the request with `c`).

[image: ESS]

### The question

These seem to be related problems. What are these messages? How can I suppress them? How can I regain control of the R console automatically in Emacs/ESS after having used a graphical device?

---

### Edit

These messages are logged in `system.log` and seem to trickle down unfiltered onto the R console. 
Here is an extract

```
Mar 14 12:56:41 xxx-mbp.att.net Google Chrome[1075]: didBecomeActive!
Mar 14 12:56:44 xxx-mbp.att.net Adium[17018]: didBecomeActive!
Mar 14 12:56:45 xxx-mbp.att.net Emacs[5455]: didBecomeActive!
Mar 14 12:56:46 xxx-mbp.att.net Google Chrome[1075]: didBecomeActive!
Mar 14 12:56:47 xxx-mbp.att.net R[16531]: didBecomeActive!
Mar 14 12:56:49 xxx-mbp.att.net Google Chrome[1075]: didBecomeActive!
Mar 14 12:56:53 xxx-mbp.att.net R[16531]: didBecomeActive!
Mar 14 12:56:54 xxx-mbp.att.net Emacs[5455]: didBecomeActive!
Mar 14 12:56:56 xxx-mbp.att.net Google Chrome[1075]: didBecomeActive!
```

Comment: Don't know the cause. As to ESS, do pressing "RET" or C-c C-c help?

Comment: Neither help and the mini-buffer complains that `Text is read only`.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with R. 
A quick search turns up didBecomeActive referenced in relation to GKTurnBasedEventListener on Apple's developer site. You may have (had?) a turn-based game running elsewhere on your system (which may have crashed and lost its way leaving a thread still running) and your R session is getting signals meant for the "old" pid.
A quick reboot should fix it or open a new terminal and ps aux to possibly see the errant thread and kill -9 it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately rebooting does not help. I had the same issue on different machines and versions of OSX (10.7, 10.8, 10.9). No games on any of these machines.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a proper answer, but you may be able to at least avoid this by redirecting stderr to a file when  you start it up ?

```
rcmd > stdout.log 2> stderr.log
```

You may also be able to play with the R sink() function to try to suppress this stuff.